# PHP list() equivalent in Python

Tags: php, python

Is there any equivalent to the PHP list() function in python?  For example:

PHP:

```php
list($first, $second, $third) = $myIndexArray;
echo "First: $first, Second: $second";
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
>>> a, b, c = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print a, b, c
1 2 3
```

Or a direct translation of your case:

```
>>> myIndexArray = [1, 2, 3]
>>> first, second, third = myIndexArray
>>> print "First: %d, Second: %d" % (first, second)
First: 1, Second: 2
```

Python implements this functionality by calling the `__iter__` method on the right-side expression and assigning each item to the variables on the left-side.  This lets you define how a custom object should be unpacked into a multi-variable assignment:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...   def __iter__(self):
...     return iter([1, 2, 3])
... 
>>> a, b, c = MyClass()
>>> print a, b, c
1 2 3
```

Comment: Sweet. That's a whole lot more info than I needed, and that's awesome!